# Next.js 13.4.2: Navigation between pages in `/app` and `/pages` folders causes full app reload

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have next pages:

```
/app
  /example
    /page.tsx
  /example-2
    /page.tsx

/pages
  /test-page.tsx
```

Redirects between `example` and `example-2` work fine, but navigation between `example` and `test-page` causes a full app reload.
I tried to use `Link` component `<Link href="/test-page">test page</Link>` and button with `replace('/example')` handler, but the behaviour is the same.

I guess it is because `/app` and `/pages` are using different "apps", but maybe there is some workaround?

Comment: Just bumped into a similar issue, how did you go about resolving it?

Comment: Still didn't find any solution

Comment: I came across a recent [discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/49849) in the Next.js repository, and it appears that is the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

try using [router](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router) instead

```
...
const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    router.push(href);
    // or router.replace() if want to disable back action to current page
  };
 
  return (
    <a href={href} onClick={handleClick} style={style}>
      {children}
    </a>
  )
...
```

EDIT: saw after answering XD

If you're trying to redirect from one app to another this will not work because they are in different domains, different servers, etc...
Router or Link only works on same app and only with files inside `pages` folder

Comment: It is the same app, but using different Next.js approaches :(

Comment: If it's the same project router or link gonna work only in files inside `pages` folder. Maybe you should add some logic in your page to render desired `example` component or maybe create an example page inside pages folder and check if user can see this page and if does, you render the content. If don't just replace the route with `router`.